# Delete Dialogflow/Actions on Google Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I had created a Dialogflow Agent, and wanted to build an Google Assistant App via the Dialogflow Integration.

Now it seems that i have 
 - Dialogflow Agent
 - Actions on Google Project
 - Google Cloud Project

But i can't delete this stuff again. :(

**Deletion of Dialogflow Agent throws error:** 
Agent can not be deleted because agent is shared with other users

BUT: In the Shared Tab there is no other user!

**Deletion in the Google Cloud Console**
Error: That there is a Project Lock
Es liegt eine Projektsperre vor.
Tracking-Nummer: 711.....

What should i do with this Tracking Number?

**Deletion in the Actions for Google Console:
Error: 
Please delete the agent in Dialogflow first.

Can someone please help me?

Kind Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Dialogflow Dashboard   http://dialogflow.com
Click on all agent then
the select agent which you want to delete.

then come on Action on Google page and then delete Actions on Google Project

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you created the project through [dialog flow](https://console.dialogflow.com/), so you need to delete the project from there first and then from google actions console.